# How to create this table effect in Microsoft word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

How can I create the following effects (red circles) for a table in Microsoft word?

[image]

Comment: You could fake it by putting a column at the beginning and end with the cells merged and veritical text.  You'd just need some unicode chars to make the brackets.

Comment: @Paul: consider posting an answer.